# API request to Yahoo using oAuth & Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I've gotten the oAuth request working.  I have the token back, and I'm able to get the signature and other variables necessary.  However, I'm not exactly sure what to do with them to make the request for content.  I've tried about a million different things, and none worked.  So, here is what I have so far:

After authenticating with oAuth, I have the following variables:

> {'oauth_body_hash': '2jmj7l5rS.....YBwk=', u'oauth_nonce':
>   u'05141181', u'oauth_timestamp': 1401657766, u'oauth_consumer_key':
>   u'dj0yJm.....meD1iMA--', 'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
>   u'oauth_version': u'1.0', u'oauth_token':
>   u'A=tdGQU1Pfrg......DhB6kbr40A--', 'oauth_signature':
>   'WUi69.....CyL2k='}

I think I should be doing something like the below, where headers = what is posted above.

```
from requests import request
r = request(method='GET', url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20fantasysports.players%20where%20player_key%3D\'238.p.6619\'&format=json&callback=", headers=STRING_ABOVE)
```

However, I just keep getting the below message.

> Authentication Error.  The table fantasysports.players requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least USER is expected"

I'm not sure what to try next.  Sorry about the beginner question.  I'm sure this is simple stuff, but i'm still learning.